# Find all <img> tags and change style attribute

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

i am trying to find a way to get the  tag from a string and remove the style attribute .
After that i want to add my own style and keep the following text.. 
For example, i have:

```
<p><img alt="" src="images/epsth/arismagnisiakos.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 405px;" /></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>
```

end the endresult should be:

```
<p><img alt="" src="images/epsth/arismagnisiakos.jpg" style="width: 100%;" /></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>
```

I have unsuccesfully tried regex but it seems like i am too dumb to understand its functionality...

Every help would be appreciated!
Greetings from Greece
Jim

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by regex like that:

```
$str = '<p><img alt="" src="images/epsth/arismagnisiakos.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 405px;" /></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>';

$newStr = preg_replace('#<img (.+) style="(.+)" />#isU', '<img $1 style="width: 100%" />', $str);
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for my late reply... it was very helpful and easy to understand... keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

To remove height or some other property:

```
$string = '<p><img alt="" src="images/epsth/arismagnisiakos.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 405px;" /></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p' ;
$pattern = "/height:\s*\d*\s*(px|%);*/" ;
$new = preg_replace($pattern,"", $string) ;

echo htmlentities($new) ;
```

Or remove all style things and replace with own ones:

```
$string = '<p><img alt="" src="images/epsth/arismagnisiakos.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 405px;" /></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p' ;
$pattern = "/style=[\'\"][^\"|^\']*[\'\"]/" ;
$own_style = "style='width: 50%'" ;
$new = preg_replace($pattern, $own_style, $string) ;

echo htmlentities($new) ;
```

Generally using `RegExp` on HTML tags is kinda bad thing and should be avoided, but in some situations may be applicable.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply... your answer was very helpful and i used it in another problem.. sorry i cant vote both answers... 

I understand that it shouldnt be used but i had to update a database which containted these tags and doing so in 6000 entries seemed like a one way solution... got the job done and learned a bit more about regex! thanks for your time!